# How to apply Gaussian blur in a videoView Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, blur

Hi i have to apply a Gaussian blur to a video view in android, someone could help me?

-https://github.com/jrvansuita/GaussianBlur
-https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry

All the libreries talks about blur for images, it's possible apply that to a video?